# Show forbidden content to non-authorized users when viewed in a Panel(-s Node/-ized Node), not when otherwise?

Tags: panels, nodes, users

I'm using Panels Nodes (Similar functionality to Panelized nodes, if you're more familiar with that) to display a bunch of content from sundry content types -- for instance, I have a content type called Front Page Slideshow, within which each node is a slide that is placed as a piece of Panels content (For simplicity sake, let's just call it a Pane) on the front page.

However, I don't want each individual slide node showing up in either internal or external search results, so I've used [Content Access](http://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) to prevent access to the individual nodes comprising the front page panes but allow access to the Panels Node content type.

Alas, doing this hides all of the panes inside of the Panels as well.

**How would one prevent access to specific content types *only* when they're being viewed individually and *not* when they're being viewed via a Panel, `in a way that also hides them from search results?`**

*N.B. I'm talking about types of nodes that can be created with individual Panels configurations -- **NOT** Panels pages. So, I don't have access to things like contexts and selection rules and whathaveyou.*

Thanks!

Comment: Some relevant related posts:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-i-hide-drupal-nodes-that-shouldnt-be-directly-accessed-from-users-and-se
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/how-to-prevent-access-to-views-only-content/5651#5651
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/display-node-through-panels-but-limit-deny-access-directly
(Leaving open because I'm curious whether this can be done via Content Access)

Comment: Worth noting that [Rabbit Hole](http://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) is a project that does something really close to what I'm wanting, but it [doesn't hide items from search results](https://drupal.org/node/1468302).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do two things.

1. I install [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole), and configure those nodes/content types to be inaccessible.
2. I install [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search), and configure it to exclude those content types from search results.

IIRC, there is an issue open for Rabbit Hole about excluding nodes/types from search, but I don't think there has been any progress or real discussion on it.

Also take a look at [Don't index certain content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33717/dont-index-certain-content-types) for another approach for handling the search results.